# Determining the Distribution of an uncorrelated Random Variable by using Dirac's Delta

Tags: independence, uniform-distribution, dirac-delta, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Choosing random variables $X \sim U(-1,1)$ and $Y = X^2$, it is possible to show that X and Y are uncorrelated, yet not independent.

I was wondering what the probability distribution of $Y$ now looks like.
We should have
$$P_Y(y) = \int_{-1}^{1}dx~~\frac{1}{2} \delta(x^2-y),$$
where $\delta$ denotes Dirac's delta distribution.

My first intuition would be to go for a substitution via $u = x^2$, but this is bad for the domain of integration.
So to circumvent this inconvenience, I would take the integration domain into an indicator function $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$.
Concatenating those ideas, I have
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{2 \sqrt{u}}~~\biggr(\chi_{[-1,0]}(- \sqrt{u}) + \chi_{[0,1]}( \sqrt{u})\biggr) \delta(u-y)~=~\frac{1}{4\sqrt{y}}\biggr(\chi_{[-1,0]}(- \sqrt{y}) + \chi_{[0,1]}( \sqrt{y})\biggr).$$

Are parts of this solution correct?
How should one proceed to arrive at the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to do the change of variables $du=  2x dx$.

In any case, working with the CDF of $Y$ avoids dealing with the Dirac delta and the degenerate joint distribution.

One can show
$$P(Y \le y) = P(X^2 \le y) = \begin{cases} 0 & y \le 0 \\ \sqrt{y} & 0 < y < 1 \\ 1 & y \ge 1\end{cases}$$
since in the case $y \in (0,1)$ we have $P(X^2 \le y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y})$.

Now that you have the CDF of $Y$, you can find the PDF by differentiating.